# Modifying object in array is changing the session value

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7, laravel-8

I have following piece of code in PHP Laravel that has array of objects. Each object has 2 attributes. Id and name. This whole object is being saved in session. Then after saving, I am removing the id from each object in the array. This is also modifying the session.

Am I doing something wrong?

```
$array = [];

$obj = new \stdClass();
$obj->id = "1";
$obj->name = "Test";

array_push($array, $obj);

$request->session()->put('val', $array);

foreach($array as $key => $val) {
    unset($array[$key]->id);
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($request->session()->get('val'));
echo "</pre>";
```

here, I noticed that id attribute is gone from session.

Comment: Yes because you are editing the same copy of the array.

Comment: @nice_dev - Can you please correct the code?

Comment: What's the point of unset? Do you want to keep separate copies of that array in session as well as usual array?

Comment: @nice_dev:  I am sending the new array as response to front end. In front end, id attribute is not needed,

Comment: Are sessions useful when having front end and backend on 2 different frameworks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue arises because the same copy of the object is being manipulated. To solve this, you will need to `clone` the object and then unset and send in response keeping data in session intact.

```
$cloned_data = [];
foreach($array as $key => $val) {
    $new_obj = clone $val;
    unset($new_obj->id);
    $cloned_data[] = $new_obj;
}

print_r($cloned_data);
```

Answer (score 0):

For sending only the names to the frontend you can use collection pluck to get a new array of just names

```php
$dataForFrontend = collect($array)->pluck('name')->all();
```

> This is changing the view of data to be send to front end. [0] => 'Test'

If you need to key it by name - something like `[0]['name'] => 'Test'`

```php
$dataForFrontend = collect($data)->map(
    fn($item) => ['name' => $item->name]
)->all();
```

If there's need to retain the array elements as objects of original type, essentially same as @nice_dev's solution

```php
$dataForFrontend = collect($array)->map(function($item) {
    $clone = clone $item;
    unset($clone->id);

    return $clone;
})->all();
```

To retain the array elements as objects - not of original type but as objects of std class

```php
$dataForFrontend = collect($data)->map(
    fn($item) => (object)['name' => $item->name]
)->all();
```

Comment: This is changing the view of data to be send to front end. `[0] => 'Test'`